# Can I have more than two routers in the same HSRP group?

Tags: router, hsrp

I want to know if it is possible to do HSRP with 3 or more routers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible. From Cisco's [HSRP documentation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/internetworking/case/studies/cs009.html):

> HSRP allows two or more
>   HSRP-configured routers to use the MAC
>   address and IP network address of a
>   virtual router.

It works really the same as two, except instead of 1 in two holding the virtual ip, 1 in 3 will hold the virtual IP.  By setting priorities,  you can set preferences as to which will have it when all three are up, or if only two are up.